# Are the media files written in Mac are different than the files in Windows,

Tags: css

I wrote a bunch of media files for a website in CSS on Mac, but when I transported them on Windows, then none of them worked. Are there different CSS selectors for Windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can only help with as much information as you have given.

Check the permissions of the files. The last time I had that problem it was from the file permissions. Also check all the file paths if anything is changed.

Comment: I just found that the a meta line was missing: <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">